# Named r-value reference binding vs assignment

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

A named rvalue reference in an lvalue, but it is an lvalue which can only bind to an rvalue, so:

```
int&& x = 5; // Ok because 5 is an rvalue
int&& y = x; // Error: You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference
```

Ok so then why is it that I **can** assign after binding the reference `y` to an rvalue?

```
int&& x = 5;
int&& y = 8;
y = x;  // Ok! This compiles!
```

`x` and `y` are both named rvalue references, so both are lvalues. Why can I bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference here, and why can I do it here but not in one line as shown in the first code snippet (`int&& y = x;`)?

Comment: Not binding ≠ binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` and `y` are lvalues whose types are rvalue references. Those references are being bound to temporary `int`s, whose lifetimes are extended to match the lifetimes of the references.

The expression `y = x` does not rebind `y`'s reference. That is not possible, a reference cannot be rebound.  Instead, it reads the *value* of the `int` referred by `x` and then assigns that value to the `int` referred by `y`.

A reference is a reference, period. The *type* of reference dictates whether it refers to an existing lvalue variable or to a temporary rvalue variable. You can't have a reference to a reference, that is not a thing in C++, which is why this code:

```
int&& x = 5;
int&& y = x;
```

doesn't compile.

But, this code:

```
int&& x = 5;
int&& y = std::move(x);
y = 7;
```

does compile, and works as you are expected (ie, assigning to `y` changes the value of the `int` that `x` refers to).

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/CINEuQ)

Comment: If I have an lvalue reference and I assign to it:
`int x = 5; int& y = x; y = 7;`
I would change the value of `x` by assigning `y` like that. I guess there is no such effect for this example with rvalue references as we just assigned literals.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example you are not binding anything, that's just assignment, `operator=`.

Comment: Notably, it's assignment *of the int*, not of the reference.